# .each() function conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, each, conflict

I don't know exactly what information is needed for this issue, but I have a jQuery function which stops a number of other scripts on my site. Here's the code that's causing the problem:

```
$('div.menu_list').each(function() {
    var id = parseInt(this.id.replace("list", ""));
    var div = '#list'+id;
    $(div).nestable({
        group: 1
    })
    .on('change', {id: id}, updateOutput);
    updateOutput($(div));
});
```

If I remove the each/loop around the code then the other scripts work fine, however this stops the current script working how it should.

```
var updateOutput = function (event) {
    var list = event.length ? event : $(event.target), output = list.data('output');
    var id = event.data.id;
    if(window.location.host){
        var base = /:\/\/([^\/]+)/.exec(window.location.href)[1];
    }else{
        var base = window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.host;
    }
    if (window.JSON) {
        value = window.JSON.stringify(list.nestable('serialize'));
        if(id){
            //$.post(window.location.pathname, {id: id, value: value });
            $.ajax({
                url: window.location.origin+"/sa_update/settings/",
                type: "post",
                data: {id: id, value: value}
            });
        }
    } else {
        return ('JSON browser support required for this demo.');
    }
};
```

Through trial and error I believe that the issues is this:

```
$(e.target)
```

Comment: The id variable is defined within the first line of the each loop. This script works fine, it just conflicts with other scripts, which is what I need to rectify.

Comment: Did you put `console.log()` to see if it runs endlessly for some reason?

Comment: Do you realize that `$(div)` is the same as `$(this)`, so you don't need that variable?

Comment: Can you show the definition of `updateOutput`? The way you're using it with `on` implies that it takes an event as the argument, but when you call it directly you're passing a jQuery collection.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue on jsFiddle.net?

Comment: @ced-b yes I tried the console.log() and the script only runs the amount of times required, which at the moment it 3.

Comment: @Barmar $(div) is not the same as $(this), as 'this' refers to the class and 'div' refers to the ID. The function updateOutput does use the event and simply uses the ID tag to get the contents and serialize using JSON and then enter this into the database. I have added the script.

Comment: @j08691 I'm afraid that I cannot recreate it as I am not sure where the conflict is occurring within the other files. Sorry

Comment: @Paul Inside `.each()`, `this` refers to the current element in the iteration, not the class. Otherwise, how would `this.id` get you the ID you want?